# if a number in column is negative,show positive,else show the number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, iif

I have a [Preko]column in a query that is calculating the difference between two columns.If the number is negative,I need to show it positive,and if it is positive,it should stay the same.I can't use ABS in this one.I tried with the case,but it didn't work.
The problem I am getting is that column Preko is invalid.

This is the code for my second try with iif:

```
SELECT FP.Firma
      ,FP.NazFirme
      ,FP.Konto
      ,FP.NazivKonta
      ,FP.Partner
      ,FP.NazivPartnera
      ,Sum(FP.Duguje) AS dug
      ,Sum(FP.Potrazuje) AS pot
      ,Sum(IIf([FP].[Konto] Like '2*'
      ,[duguje]-[potrazuje]
      ,[potrazuje]-[duguje])) AS USaldo
      ,Sum(IIf([datumval]<= '1.1.2017'
      ,IIf([FP].[Konto] Like '2*'
      ,[duguje]-[potrazuje]
      ,[potrazuje]-[duguje]),0)) AS [Preko]
      ,IIf([Preko]<0,0,[Preko]) AS Preko1
FROM tblFinansijskiPodaci FP
Where FP.Firma = 1 
AND FP.Partner=1110
GROUP BY FP.Firma
        ,FP.NazFirme
        ,FP.Konto
        ,FP.NazivKonta,
        ,FP.Partner
        ,FP.NazivPartnera 
HAVING (((FP.Konto)=2040))
```

Comment: Please format you code so we can read it more easily. Why can't you use `ABS`? "I tried with the case,but it didn't work" doesn't really help. What did you try, why didn't it work?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I'd guess MSAccess.  I think there's an IIF there.

Comment: @xQbert Could also be sql-server 2012+: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql

Comment: @MatSnow good point that.   Interesting... "The fact that IIF is translated into CASE also has an impact on other aspects of the behavior of this function."  So the engine makes iif case... and all therefore all rules applying to case, also apply to IIF.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using sql server 2014.They have added iif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a case statement instead of the iif section.

```
  CASE WHEN Preko<0 THEN 0 ELSE Preko END
```

or

```
  CASE WHEN Preko<0 THEN -Preko ELSE Preko END
```

That seems to be more in line with your logic depending on how you want to handle the negatives.

Comment: Yes,but can I insert this part after the "..AS Preko"? Or I have to combine in it?

Comment: You can either wrap the main query in a cte then select *, CASE WHEN Preko<0 THEN -Preko ELSE Preko END as Preko1 FROM cte OR substitute the formula for preko into the case.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with HoneyBadger - ABS is the way to go ABS(-1) returns 1.  Have a look at the APEX SQL tools for a quick formatting option.  It's free and makes your code a lot easier to read, which means you'll find you get more answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT FP.Firma
      ,FP.NazFirme
      ,FP.Konto
      ,FP.NazivKonta
      ,FP.Partner
      ,FP.NazivPartnera
      ,Sum(FP.Duguje) AS dug
      ,Sum(FP.Potrazuje) AS pot
      ,Sum(IIf([FP].[Konto] Like '2*'
      ,[duguje]-[potrazuje]
      ,[potrazuje]-[duguje])) AS USaldo
      ,Sum(IIf([datumval]<= '1.1.2017'
      ,IIf([FP].[Konto] Like '2*'
      ,[duguje]-[potrazuje]
      ,[potrazuje]-[duguje]),0)) AS [Preko]
FROM tblFinansijskiPodaci FP
Where FP.Firma = 1 
AND FP.Partner=1110
GROUP BY FP.Firma
        ,FP.NazFirme
        ,FP.Konto
        ,FP.NazivKonta,
        ,FP.Partner
        ,FP.NazivPartnera 
HAVING (((FP.Konto)=2040))
)
SELECT *, CASE WHEN Preko<0 THEN 0 ELSE Preko END preko1 FROM cte
```

Comment: this is the full, working answer. I have managed to done it without cte, based on your previous answer,so that's why I marked that one as the answer.both were very helpful,so thank you very much!